# What is it called when a highly respected person commits an immoral act but people don't believe that he committed the act?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I was wondering. It just came up. It has no real world relevancy. An example:

> A highly respected businessman commits child abuse and one day his
>   wife finds out about it. She shares what she had found out about with
>   the circles of the businessman. But they don't think he's guilty or
>   that he would commit such an act. Similarly the man easily slips,
>   without getting dirt on his coat and with pride.

Is the situation I stated has a definitive word for it? Is there a word for the attitude of the man and/or his circle?

Comment: Good question. I feel almost certain that there must be an expression or proverb for this, but I cannot for the life of me think of one.

Comment: I believe that's "normal".

Comment: Are there two parts to this OP? **1**) a term that characterizes the peoples disbelief, and **2**) a term for the ability to consistently evade the consequences of wrongful actions?

Comment: @LittleEva Yes. Those two definitions are what I'm after.

Comment: In your opinion then, is my answer relevant to number 1? I never addressed the second part. My apologies.

Comment: @LittleEva It's fine. I find relief in the people's desire to spend their time on my questions. I appreciate all the answers, of course, including yours. I'm just trying to wrap my head around everything before accepting an answer.

Comment: @LittleEva That's a phrase I haven't heard before. Thank you for that one as well.

Comment: That being ... [*curry favor*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/curry-favour.html)?

Comment: @LittleEva Yes. _to bring oneself into favour with someone by flattering or trying to please them_ Learning is fun.

Comment: @LittleEva Misplaced comment.

Comment: @LittleEva Didn't you mean to put `Tushar - what and/or answer? Link me up.` under your answer?

Comment: @LittleEva I didn't know that. Sorry about my boldness.

Comment: @LittleEva _Whatever you do, or dream you can, begin it. Boldness has genius and power and magic in it_?

Comment: I'm afraid that almost exactly the scenario you describe has occurred in the real world. I'm of course referring to [Jimmy Savile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Savile_sexual_abuse_scandal). It's entirely possible that the adjective or noun you're looking for has been used to describe him in the hundreds of news items about this scandal.

Comment: Concur with the above comment, JS got away scot-free, (the accusations came after his death) and I'll add [Rolf Harris](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/crime/rolf-harris-child-abuse-images-stash-found-under-floorboards-by-plumber-40-years-ago-9589111.html) onto the heap (a children's entertainer/singer/accomplished painter/charity donor etc.) The latter was recently sentenced to prison. The word that came up most often in my mind when I first heard about RH's crimes was **disbelief**. He seemed such a totally respectable and nice guy.

Comment: It's spending one's reputation, getting away with a one-off because many don't expect any particular day to be the one that someone pulls such a stunt.

Comment: There is an interesting contrast between this fallacy and the [no *true* scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) fallacy; they're practically inverses of one another. This halo effect is rejecting a specific claim by reasoning broadly about the subject, while *no true Scotsman* is reclassifying a broad claim to disqualify a specific subject from providing a counterexample. (I just thought that was interesting.)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is an instance of the [Halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect):

> Halo effect is a cognitive bias in which an observer's overall impression of a person, company, brand, or product influences the observer's feelings and thoughts about that entity's character

The businessman is respected in his profession, so everyone thinks his character, including his conduct towards children, must be respectable.

Comment: I was just about to post this. Good job.

Comment: +1, great submission and an articulation that's new to me. I was stumbling about in the dark trying to find my way to this concept, which more reasonably attributes the businessman's unsullied character and the absence of legal consequences, not to the businessman per se, but to the influence of a cognitive bias affecting the community.

Comment: And the opposite of that effect is obviously, the Horns Effect. Google it :)

Comment: I am pleasantly stupefied by the popularity this answer has achieved, dethroning the previous #1, which was 20+ upvotes ahead when I posted mine.

Comment: Has this answer been [Slashdotted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect) or something?

Comment: @DanDascalescu - This is an instance of the Hot Question effect. The question hit the "hot network questions". (See the list to the lower right of the page?) The *question*, not the answer. Your answer benefited from this because it's a good answer. Enjoy it. It happens to most of us once in a great while.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a word for the opposit direction. For example, if a person does something bad at some point in the past. Then the time pass and this person can improve his/her behaviour. But somehow the society does not see he/she as a reliable person. Of course there are some acts that are very difficult to recover. But let's say that the acts were just as a lack of broad knoledge in my example.

Answer (score 35):

The attributive noun **Teflon** (semi-genericised) is often used:

> Teflon
>
> 1. Trademark. a fluorocarbon polymer with slippery, nonsticking properties: used in the manufacture of electrical insulation, cookware
>      coatings, etc. ...
> 2. characterized by imperviousness to blame or criticism: a Teflon politician.

{[RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Teflon)}

> It would make of Gorbachev's stewardship a truly Teflon chairmanship,
>   demonstrating that no Soviet actions, regardless of how egregious,
>   will cling to him

(New Republic; same link).

> 'Teflon Don' cleared of three killings will have his £2m home seized
>   as High Court judge brands him a drug dealer

{[Mail Online](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2109401/Teflon-Don-cleared-killings-2m-home-seized-High-Court-judge-brands-drug-dealer.html)}

The phrase **above the law** is also relevant:

> above the law  [Prepositional phrase]
>
> (idiomatic) Exempt from the laws that apply to everyone else.
>
> *The emperor is above the law.*

{[Wiktionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/above-the-law)}

> He thinks he's above the law BECAUSE people treat him as if he's above
>   the law.[of G W Bush]

{[Perspectives](http://www.perspectives.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=55451)}

Comment: _Teflon_ is good!  +1.

Comment: The Mafia boss, John Gotti was referred to as the "Teflon Don." What did they call Bill Clinton?

Comment: *Teflon* is fairly new. What did we say before *teflon*?

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. Everyone believes these people did what they were accused of, but they did not receive negative repercussions (hence Teflon). The OP is asking more for things like Lance Armstrong before it was widely believed he used doping.

Comment: @Eric OP asks (naughtily, perhaps) for more than one response. 'Is there a word for the attitude of the man ...' shows that OP does not require everyone involved to have the wrong impression (which would be impossible anyway). 'Above the law' is also relevant. Though I'd agree that 'halo effect' and 'can do no wrong' are better answers.

Comment: @medica _Blush_. But isn't that sexist?

Answer (score 29):

Such a person [*can do no wrong*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-can-do-no-wrong)

> used for saying that someone is considered by other people to be perfect, although you may not agree with this opinion
>   *His parents think he can do no wrong.*

---

He might also be called [above the law](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define:above+the+law)

> in a position where one can avoid being bound by the laws that govern ordinary people.
>   *"the army was above the law and enjoyed complete impunity"*

Or [untouchable](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define:untouchable)

> not able or allowed to be touched or affected.
>   *"drug barons who were legally untouchable"*

The cause of these latter two could be that everyone believes him innocent; however it could also because people believe him too powerful and dangerous to be stopped.

---

And, to some extent (i.e. literally), the person is a [hypocrite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hypocrite)

> a person who pretends to have virtues, moral or religious beliefs, principles, etc., that he or she does not actually possess, especially a person whose actions belie stated beliefs.

Comment: "Above the law" means absence of prosecution/punishment. Perhaps "above suspicion" would be more accurate?

Comment: @TemplateRex You're right, except that reminds me of Caesar's wife, and the reason it was said was because she *wasn't* above suspicion.

Comment: Added a new answer with *unimpeachable* and *irreproachable*

Comment: "Paragon of virtue" is another one along these lines

Comment: No, because I think a "paragon of virtue" is someone who is genuinely virtuous.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this is an example of an "**abuse of trust**."

[**Abuse of Trust**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Abuse+of+trust)

**References in periodicals archive**

> **IPCC Commissioner for Wales Tom Davies said: "This was an appalling abuse of trust by a police officer dealing with three vulnerable women who expected the police to protect them.** *Two officers are suspended over sex cop claims; Policemen face ... by South Wales Echo (Cardiff, Wales)*
>
> **Health and Care Professions Council panel chairman Claire Bonnet said: "This was an abuse of trust.** *Paramedic struck off for sex act by Sunday Mirror (London, England)*

(The Free Dictionary)

A word for the peoples reaction might be **incredulous**, i.e., *the people are incredulous, or express **incredulity**, that a person held in such high regard could ever have committed such outrageous acts*.

Possibly, the people are *incredulous* because they have invested their trust in this respected businessman, so that even contemplating such an affront to morality threatens to undermine their faith in the status quo, after all, if *this* man is capable of such a shocking act, how many others might conceivably also be as corrupt? Another possible barrier to acceptance is that those who express such disbelief are themselves corrupt and would rather avoid the whole subject matter.

> [**incredulous**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredulous) *adjective*
>
> **1**: unwilling to admit or accept what is offered as true : not credulous : skeptical
>
> **2**: incredible
>
> **3**: expressing incredulity
>
> [**incredulity**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredulity) *noun*: a feeling that you do not or cannot believe or accept that something is true or real

(Merriam-Webster *online*)

In this age of *Kali Yuga*, where each new day brings a myriad of fresh scandal - perpetrated by our elected representatives, healers & holy men, business leaders and law enforcement officers - what can possibly account for this incredulity? Does it really stem from the attributes of the perpetrators? Are they truly Teflon-coated, untouchable, above the law and beyond reproach?

Me thinks not! Only a form of collective denial - a willing (*but unconscious*) blindness - could possibly account for the phenomena attested to in this OP. What 's the name for that? **See Dan Dascalescu's spot-on answer**.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the key point is not that this person will not only not be *prosecuted or punished* (as expressed by being *above the law*), but not even be *suspected or criticized* as expressed by:

- **unimpeachable**: not able to be doubted, questioned, or criticized; entirely trustworthy

Comment: If you call someone "irreproachable" that doesn't usually mean you think they *ought* to be reproached: it means that you're among the people who believe they're blameless.

Comment: If you think they should be reproached, and want to talk about the fact that people in general will be resistant to the suggestion, you could say that someone "is usually thought to be beyond reproach, but this new information will show that perhaps they shouldn't be."

Answer (score 4):

Such a person is usually called a **sacred cow**.

**Definition**: [Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/sacred+cow)

- One that is immune from criticism, often unreasonably so

**Example**:

- *Peer review is often thought of as ancient and unchanging, but it is neither – and it shouldn’t be treated as a sacred cow* ([Times](https://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/features/peer-review-not-old-you-might-think))

Comment: I've never heard of a *person* being called a sacred cow. Ideas, yes. People, no.

Comment: @AaronHall: Agreed it is more popular with things. But it is sometimes used with people too. See for example: http://www.theglobeandmail.com/arts/television/will-true-detective-be-the-hit-rachel-mcadams-needs/article25038245/

Comment: In the US, being called a cow would be something of an insult. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cow) definition 4. *Slang: Disparaging and Offensive.* a. a large, obese, and slovenly woman.

Comment: @PatrickM: Calling someone a "sacred cow" wouldn't have any of the same implications as calling someone a "cow".  The phrase is well enough known that people would recognize the usage, even though it's non-standard (usually for ideas, not people).  Taking offense at it would be a stretch, but probably doable for someone that liked to twist the words of their opponents.

Comment: Some delight in double entendres. I could certainly see it used for that effect intentionally, especially since this is such an obscure usage, and I don't think it would be a stretch to take offense at it at all.

Comment: Christopher Hitchens wrote an exposé about Mother Theresa. He wanted to call it "Sacred Cow" but the title was rejected by the publisher as too controversial. Too bad: it was an *excellent* pun considering the contents of the book. He had to settle for "The Missionary Position." Much less effective.

Answer (score 2):

They're giving him the [benefit of the doubt](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+benefit+of+the+doubt)

> Regard someone as innocent until proven otherwise; lean toward a favorable view of someone. *For example, Let's give her the benefit of the doubt and assume that she's right.* [Mid-1800s]

Specifically, the second definition of this idiom in reference to giving the benefit of the doubt to someone:

> to believe something good about someone, rather than something bad, when you have the possibility of doing either *After hearing his explanation, I was prepared to give him the benefit of the doubt.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it really applies here, but in the described situation you could say there is a kind of `reality distortion field` in effect. This is the term that was used to describe the charismatic properties of the appearances of Steve Jobs. But this is ofcourse not related to a-moral behaviour of any kind.

Another term that springs to mind is `groupthink`.

> Groupthink is a psychological phenomenon that occurs within a group of
>   people, in which the desire for harmony or conformity in the group
>   results in an irrational or dysfunctional decision-making outcome.
>   Group members try to minimize conflict and reach a consensus decision
>   without critical evaluation of alternative viewpoints, by actively
>   suppressing dissenting viewpoints, and by isolating themselves from
>   outside influences.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink)

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you are looking for is Privilege

The usual definition is:

> A special right, advantage, or immunity granted or available only to a particular person or group of people.

Many people also use the word to describe how different people in a society are judged by different rules, depending what groups they belong to.  The businessman in your example is assumed to be innocent by the people in his circle (in part) because they assume financial success somehow correlates with being a good person.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_(social_inequality) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

An uncommon but very fitting expression is "citizen above suspicion", from the movie [Investigation of a Citizen Above Suspicion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065889/) (Indagine su un cittadino al di sopra di ogni sospetto) which revolves around a respected member of the society getting away for his wrongdoings, even despite all his attempts to get the punishment he deserves.

Answer (score 0):

The highly respected businessman is "sitting in the catbird seat" from a short story called The Catbird Seat by James Thurber.

Comment: Neither the meaning of "sitting in the catbird seat" nor the point of the story.

Comment: I respected person who never did anything wrong or deviated from his usual routine plans and commits murder and no one believes he could do it.